# Linked SQL Server's table shows all fields as #Deleted, but when converted to local, all information is there

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My company has a really old Access 2003 .ADP front-end connected to an on-premise SQL Server. I was trying to update the front-end to MS Access 2016, which is what we're transitioning to, but when linking the tables I get all the fields in this specific table as #Deleted. I've looked around and tried to change some of the settings, but I'm really not that into SQL Server to know what I'm doing, hence asking for help.

When converting the table to local, all the info is correctly displayed, so it begs the question. Also, skipping to the last record will reveal the info on that record, or sorting/filtering reveals some of the records, but most of the table stays "#Deleted"...

Since I know you're going to ask: Yes, I need to edit the records.. Although the snapshot method would work for people trying to view the info, some of us need to edit it.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this,

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the CREATE TABLE statement for the problematic table. Some SQL Server data types don't work well with Access. Also, which ODBC driver do you use for linking the tables?

Comment: It's not `SQLServer` but `SQL Server`.

Comment: Ever thought about serving Access 2003 as [RemoteApp](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/terminal-services/remoteapp.htm) while the clients run Office 2016. Quite sure there will be more traps while converting an ADP to ACCDB.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 common reasons for this:

You have bit fields in SQL server, but they are null. They should be assigned a default of 0.

The table in question does NOT have a PK (primary key).

Last but not least you need (want) to add a timestamp column. Keep in mind that this is really what we call a “row version” column (so it not a date/time column, but a timestamp column). Adding this column will help access determine if a record been changed, and this is especially the case for any table/form in Access that allows editing of “real” number data types (single, double). If access does not find a timestamp column, then it reverts to a column by column comparison to determine table changes, and due to how computers handle “real” numbers (with rounding), then such comparisons often fail.

So, check for the above 3 issues. You likely should re-run the linked table manager have making any changes.